# JQuery-UI Draggable locked to the window

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-ui, draggable

I created a really simple map and I wanted it to be dragable.

Here is the code:
http://jsfiddle.net/AeABp/

It works, I can move the map around how I want. But I want it to be locked to the "window", so that there is never white space when it get dragged, I hope you understand what I mean.
I also had a look at the the overview from jquery-ui, but didn't find anything that I needed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to constrain movement to a set of coordinates to make it work properly. Took a bit of messing with, but the containment constrains the element based on the top left corner of the element.

```
$(function() {
    var con = $('#container');
    var cw = con.width( ), ch = con.height( );
    var map = $('#map');
    var mw = map.width( ), mh = map.height( );
    var x1 = -mw + cw, y1 = -mh + ch;
    map.draggable({containment:[x1,y1,0,0]});
});
```

Comment: This doesn't work for me. Does #container need to have some css? con.width() and con.height() yield null for me.

Answer (score 0):

There's an easy way to do it (if i understood well):

```
$('#map').draggable({
    containment: 'window',
    scroll: false
});
```